# Ubuntu can not use Intel SSD during installation

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I changed my hard disk to Intel SSDSC2CW240A3 (240GB SSD) and want install Ubuntu. But Ubuntu can not recognize the SSD. So I install win7 first and retry from USB(remove win7 and install Ubuntu). But it can not recognize SSD either. Only get the picture at the **installation type**  step (sdb is my USB stick and sda is the 240GB SSD):

[image: picture link]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            2.3G  411M  1.9G  18% /
udev            2.3G  4.0K  2.3G   1% /dev
tmpfs           468M  1.2M  467M   1% /run
/dev/sdb        1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2.3G  1.1M  2.3G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            2.3G  224K  2.3G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   76K  100M   1% /run/user

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 1 GiB, 1115594752 bytes, 2178896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfe83fffa

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 222013439 221806592 105.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       222013440 468856831 246843392 117.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.9 GiB, 2003828736 bytes, 3913728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4a022e4f

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 2271359 2271360  1.1G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       2250448 2254991    4544  2.2M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l print
Model: ATA INTEL SSDSC2CW24 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   114GB  114GB  primary  ntfs
 3      114GB   240GB  126GB  primary  ntfs


Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Model: Netac OnlyDisk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8015MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      1152MB  1155MB  2327kB               EFI
```

I only want install one system Ubuntu(no dual-boot ).Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use **gparted** to delete all 3 partitions of SSD(sda) and build the SSD to ext4, then Ubuntu can use SSD to install.
I think the reason is the initial file system format or the partition of SSD.